# action creators not available as functions in props when passed directly to connect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
import * as actions from '../actions';

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  actions
)(MyComponent);
```

I imported actions and passed it to connect as follows.
I have an action creator called authenticate.
When I console.log(this.props), it shows the state mapped using mapStateToProps()
But it does not show the authenticate function in props list. I thought we can use actions like this without having to write a mapDispatchToProps() function. Why is this not working?

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';

import App from './components/app';
import Home from './components/home';
import reducers from './reducers';

import '../styles/style.css';

const store = createStore(reducers);

ReactDOM.render(
  <MuiThemeProvider>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
          <div>
            <Route path="/"  component={App}/>
            <Route path="/home" component={Home}/>
          </div>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
  , document.getElementById('app'));
```

actions/index.js

```
import { CHANGE_AUTH } from './constants';

export default function authenticate(isLoggedIn) {
  return {
    type: CHANGE_AUTH,
    payload: isLoggedIn
  };
}
```

components/app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import * as actions from '../actions';

class App extends Component {
  authButton = () => {
    if(this.props.authenticated) {
      return <RaisedButton label="Sign out" onClick={this.props.authenticate(false)} />
    }

    return <RaisedButton label="Sign out" onClick={this.props.authenticate(true)} />
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
        <div>{this.authButton()}</div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { authenticated: state.authenticated };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(App);
```

reducers/authentication.js

```
import { CHANGE_AUTH } from '../actions/constants';

export default function(state = false, action ) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHANGE_AUTH:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import authenticationReducer from './authentication';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  authenticated: authenticationReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

This is the entire code. I'm not sure why the action creators are not on props.

When I did this.props.authenticate(false) in authButton() function in components/app.js, I got the error his.props.authenticate is not a function.

These are the dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "material-ui": "^0.20.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "redux": "^3.7.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing the actions directly to connect like

```
import * as actions from '../actions';

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  actions
)(MyComponent);
```

works.

According to the documentation of connect [`mapDispatchToProps`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options)

> If an object is passed, each function inside it is assumed to be a
>   Redux action creator. An object with the same function names, but with
>   every action creator wrapped into a dispatch call so they may be
>   invoked directly, will be merged into the component’s props.

The error in your case is that you are exporting the action `authenticate` as a default export and when you import it like

```
import * as actions from '../actions';
```

the authenticate action is imported by the name `default` and hence can be used from props like `this.props.default(true)`. Instead you should `export` it as a `named export` like

```
import { CHANGE_AUTH } from './constants';

export function authenticate(isLoggedIn) {
  return {
    type: CHANGE_AUTH,
    payload: isLoggedIn
  };
}
```

and then your would be able to access it like `this.props.authenticate()`

Comment: Hi, I added the entire code that I've written.. please have a look. I don't see the action creator inside console when I log the this.props. I also get the error this.props.authenticate() is not a function when I try to use the authenticate action creator.

Comment: @sruthisripathi updated the answer with the explanation of why it was not working for you

Answer (score 0):

You have to dispatch the action. 
The connect statement should be written like

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, (dispatch) => { authenticate(arg) : dispatch(actions.authenticate(arg))})(App);
```

Comment: The question was not how to make it work but why directly having actions in connect doesn't work

Comment: hah. I misread it. You answered well, I learned something new.